# How to get wordpress plugin "Twitter hash" to show on page

Tags: wordpress, hash, twitter, widget

I cannot for my life figure out how to get the downloaded plugin Twitter hash (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-hash-tag-widget/) to show on my index.php page. Read about it and this HTML code was given as an example in many places:

```
<li id=”twitter">
<ul>
<li><a href=”http://www.site1.com/”>Site One Name</a></li>    
</ul>
</li>
```

But obviously all it does is a HTML list so it shows nothing of how to connect to the widget I have. I also added the file functions.php with the following lines:

```
<?php
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
register_sidebar();
?>
```

and dragged the widget to its place on the wordpress widget page.

All help appreciated for a very new wordpress user!

//Margareta

Answer (score 0):

Right, solved it by using the Kubrick theme instead of the simplified theme that I had used earlier. Now it is showing on the side without me doing anything. Great stuff!